Is there an in-between function or an Alternative to subprocess.Popen and subprocess.Run?
I'm creating a Python terminal on a Windows computer from scratch and I'm trying to sync the error commands and pipe them from either command prompt or Powershell which ever one the code is in. However, when I use subprocess.run, certain longer commands like netstat don't work. However, when I use subprocess.Popen, the error messages don't route from command prompt correctly.
This is the current code:
def run_os_command():
    while True:
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        command = input(f"{cwd} {current_time} >>:>> ")
        if command.lower() == "exit":
            break
        if command.lower().startswith("cd"):
            try:
                path = command.split(' ', 1)[1]  # get the path from the command
                os.chdir(path)
            except (IndexError, FileNotFoundError, NotADirectoryError):
                print("Error: Invalid directory")
        else:
            command = 'powershell ' + command
            command = command.split()
            try:
                process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
                while True:
                    output = process.stdout.readline()
                    if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
                        break
                    if output:
                        print(output.strip())
                process.poll()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Error: Command does not exist")


Tried with subprocess.Popen


:>> l


Expected:
"L" is not recognized as an external or batch command....
Obtained: the next prompt
Tried with subprocess.Run


:>> netstat


Expected:
Active Connections
Proto  Local Address    Foreign Address    State
Obtained: nothing, the command lagged indefinitely

What is your actual question? Yes, there are other ways to run external programs than subprocess.Popen and subprocess.Run but what is the exact problem you're trying to solve that those would not?

Im running a python env as an administrator, idk if you can tell, but the run_os_command opens a "terminal window" that is formatted like command prompt except for the fact that it is just inputs routed to subprocess. neither of those commands i mentioned, run and Popen are able to run all the commands and display the right errors though should i paste the full code?

Including full code would be helpful if you're not sure what exactly causes your issue. However, it's mostly unclear what your exact question is. The title asks if there are alternatives, and the text suggest that "longer commands [..] don't work" - but exactly what you're trying to achieve and how you tried to do that is unclear. Please make the problem very specific and share the code that would allow someone to reproduce your issue.

subprocess.run() is a convenience function which first calls subprocess.Popen() to create a subprocess, then Popen.communicate() to wait for it to finish and return the return code, stdout data and stderr data.
Whereas with calling subprocess.Popen(), you are only launching the subprocess and the rest is up to you. Program execution continues as soon as the process is created. You can then call Poepen.wait() to wait for completion, call Popen.communicate() to optionally send input to the subprocess and wait for completion, or write asynchronous code (by reading from stdout/stderr buffers as data is available, using poll() to determine if subprocess has completed, implementing multithreading, etc). Refer to subprocess library documentation.
The choice comes down to your needs, both methods will work.
Now onto your code...
The reason you aren't getting a FileNotFound exception for invalid commands is when you create the subprocess, you are passing it args=['powershell', 'asdflkj']--and 'powershell' IS a valid command. subprocess parses args where the first parameter is the command/application, and the rest of the list are arguments for that specific application/command.
This means you need to wait for the subprocess to complete and check the return code of the CompletedSubprocess. Any code other than 0 indicates failure. Error text will be in process.stderr
But furthermore, you don't even need to launch powershell; commands can be called directly. I did some quick benchmarks and it is significantly faster on my machine to call commands directly, both when valid and invalid.
One caveat: if you want to be able to run commands which are built in to the shell such as dir, it requires launching a shell. For this you could use shell=True argument for Popen()/run() rather than calling powershell yourself. (Online you will find people recommending avoiding shell=True for security reasons, which I'm assuming you don't need to worry about).
Here is an implementation using run():
from datetime import datetime
import os
import subprocess

while True:
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    command = input(f"{cwd} {datetime.now(): %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} >>:>> ")
    if command.strip() == '':
        continue
    if command.lower() == 'exit':
        break

    cmd, *args = command.split()
    if cmd.lower() == 'cd':
        if not args:
            print(cwd) # mirrors functionality of actual cd
            continue
        try:
            path = command.split(maxsplit=1)[1] # get the path from the command
            os.chdir(path)
        except (FileNotFoundError, NotADirectoryError):
            print('Error: Invalid directory')
        continue

    process = subprocess.run([cmd, *args],
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             text=True,
                             shell=True)
    if process.returncode != 0:
        print('Error: Command does not exist')

This approach does not pipe stdout, meaning output is printed in real-time but you can still display your own error message for invalid commands!
A few fixes/improvements:

Blank commands (like when you just hit enter) will print the next prompt line instead of launching a subprocess without arguments
cd without arguments echoes current directory instead of raising uncaught exception

If you do want to process/filter the output line-by-line in real time, you can use Popen() with piped stdout as follows:
    process = subprocess.Popen([cmd, *args],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                               text=True,
                               shell=True)
    for line in process.stdout:
        # do something with output line
        print(line.strip())
    try:
        process.wait(timeout=10)
        if process.returncode != 0:
            print('Error: Command does not exist')
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print('Error: command timed out')


Other notes...

if the user wants to terminate a subprocess via CTRL+C, you can wrap the loop in a try block and catch KeyboardInterrupt
if you search for other SO answers about subprocess/Popen, make sure you're looking at recent info--there is a lot of 10-year-old advice from when the subprocess library had bugs and lacked current functionality
depending on the scope of your project, you may want to consider checking out the cmd library. It handles the difficult parts for you so you can focus on implementing commands

